# How to use validation group in 'MVC' razor

Tags: razor

Form contains two buttons, I need to apply required field validation on 'productID' TextBox if click Search button.Similarly apply required field validation on 'Productname' & 'Description TextBox onclick Submit.
View Code :

```
Enter Product No :                       
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.productID)
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="action" />
Product Name :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Productname)
Product Description :
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Description)

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="action" />
```

Comment: Proper code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to put them in two different forms. So the input for productID goes in **form1** and the rest go in **form2**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   // inputs for form 1
   <input type="submit" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   // inputs for form 2
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

That way the validation will only trigger for the corresponding form elements.